# Depreciating companies intangible assets

Tags: corporate-finance, accounting

Companies intangible assets are something which is not physical e.g. Patents, copyrights etc.
How can we depreciate companies intangible assets and why it is done?

Comment: What is the difference between amortization and depreciating intangible asset?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about accounting principles, not economic principles. This could be migrated to [money.se]

Comment: We should hash this out in economics-meta. There are numerous journal of economic literature (JEL) codes concerning accounting and accounting is often a class taught within the economics and business schools so while @EnergyNumber's position has some merit it isn't the only valid position.

Comment: cc @Bkay Currently, Accounting is treated as off-topic in economics.se, http://economics.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic. _But_ "Business Economics" are "on topic but". It is my impression, that a question like this one falls somewhere in between.

Comment: Is this really an accounting question? Or is it on how to calibrate the depreciation rate $\delta$, given that intangible assets are more and more part of production?

Comment: Nevermind, now I saw the tags.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All assets which have a finite useful life are depreciated. For example, your patents or copyright might hold for 5 or 10 years but no more. Thus, it is quite coherent to reflect the loss of value through depreciation and amortization. Same goes for a software for example: in 5 years time, a software might be obsolete, so we need to reflect this in the financial statements.

However, the intangible assets which do not have a finite useful life (e.g. goodwill) will not be depreciated, though its value can be impaired. A great example was provided [last summer by Microsoft](http://www.bloomberg.com/news/articles/2015-07-22/microsoft-drops-as-nokia-charge-leads-to-largest-quarterly-loss).

The way it is done is the very same as for tangible assets.

Under IFRS, the relevant IAS is the [IAS 38](http://www.ifrs.org/IFRSs/IFRS-technical-summaries/Documents/IAS38-English.pdf)